# Ubuntu 18.04.3 - when trying to uninstall mongodb says that it doesn't exist, when trying to install says it exists

Tags: 18.04, mongodb

I have been working on this and read a lot of articles. I am trying to get this working on my test server hosted by digital ocean. for some reason, out of seemingly nowhere the my server couldn't connect to Mongodb, so since it's a testing and after exhausting those resources I decided to delete and reinstall, However, whenever trying to remove mongodb it says that it doesn't exist: after running `$ sudo apt-get purge mongodb mongodb-server mongodb-server-core mongodb-clients`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'mongodb' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-clients' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

so it says that it doesn't exist so after `$ sudo apt-get install mongodb-org` I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
mongodb-org is already the newest version (3.6.17).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried in both cases to do the `apt --fix-broken install` but to no avail.

when typing `$ mongo` I get

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.17
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-03-31T18:26:22.472+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2020-03-31T18:26:22.472+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:263:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

I read about unmasking, enabling, or any type of mongodb interactivity I get:

```
2020-03-31T18:26:22.472+0000: command not found
-bash: connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:263:13: No such file or directory
@(connect):1:6: command not found
exception:: command not found
-bash: root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-fra1-01:/home/name#: No such file or directory
```

I am performing all the same actions that previously did to access the db.... no clue WHAT happened.... thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you've messed up your repositories by adding additional [mongodb-org](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) repository.

Try to comment out it's source in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list` or similar file.

Then do `sudo apt update && sudo apt install -f`

Then try again: `sudo apt install mongodb` and so on.